# Two Element are referring same the Xpath in selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

**The scenario is "Upload the file using browse button".**

Have two Element (input text box , browse button) while finding the Xpath both element are referred same Xpath .(eg: //div//tr//td//input). Hence click , mouse press event, short cut keys , Tab&Enter  are not working. So used Robot class function robot.mouseMove (400,600) [x axis, y axis are hard coded].

Question: Can anyone help me to find the browse button element in a page without Xpath(since I hard coded x- axis,y-axis)?

Comment: //div//tr//td//input[1] refers to the first and  //div//tr//td//input[2] refers to the second

Comment: can you post the html code for the same

Answer (score 3):

You can add predicate to distinguish both elements:

```
//div//tr//td//input[@type="text"]
```

for input and

```
//div//tr//td//input[@type="button"]
```

for button

P.S. If input field is for file upload, then predicate should be `[@type="file"]`

Comment: Hi Andersson,<div><tr><td><input>.................</input></td></tr></div>

Comment: Hi Andersson, The code is like this only. “ <div><tr><td><input>.................</input></td></tr></div>”
It is NOT two input tags. I used robot class for mouse move since above two elements are referred same tags. But drawback is hard coded the X axis and Y axis in a robot function. Kindly help me out to find the web element in a screen without Xpath.

Comment: Two elements with same `<input>` tags, but not input tags?! How could it be? Share more details as for now your issue is quite unclear